# Simple URL Rewrite with wildcard subdomain

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to have unique subdomain address for every user like http://*.mywebsite.com where * can be any username like xyz, abc, john, deo etc.

I want that whenever somebody opens the url like http://aswt.mywebsite.com, its gets redirected to http://www.mywebsite.com/panels/users/index.php?subdomain=aswt.

Please help me in implement it as I am newbie with url rewriting. I do have tried searching on google and stack overflow but didnt found anything similarly to me or easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't do it with mod_rewrite : RewriteRule doesn't take HTTP_HOST into account. RewriteCond does but is not enough here.

You'll have to do it with PHP :

```
if (preg_match('#^(.*)\.mywebsite\.com$#', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $matches))
{
  header('Location: /panels/users/index.php?subdomain='.$matches[1];
  exit;
}
```

Should make it...

Anyway, for url-rewritings (especially for complex ones), PHP often leads to much less problems than mod_rewrite and is more powerful.

Comment: How will and where should I use this preg_match as http://aswt.mywebsite.com doesnt exist at all. I just wanted to know how this can be done using modrewrite where when anybody types http://aswt.mywebsitename.com and gets redirected to http://www.mywebsitesite.com/panels/users/index.php?subdomain=aswt

Note: Subdomain http://aswt.mobilehealthnig.com doesnt exist at all, it will be dynamic like http://username.mywebsite.com

Comment: You must use my bit of code, for instance in your root index.php . Before that you'll have to modify your website's VirtualHost in httdp.conf with `ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com` , so that all *.mywebsite.com requests will be send to your index.php.